# Windows Python packages not compatible with Amazon Linux?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pip, zbar, amazon-linux

I'm creating a layer for my lambda function by installing the dependencies locally, zipping the folder, and uploading it to S3. To ensure the packages are compatible with Lambda runtimes, I'm installing the packages like this (per the docs)

```
pip install \
    --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 \
    --target=my-lambda-function \
    --implementation cp \
    --python 3.8 \
    --only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
    packagename
```

This works for all but one package, pyzbar, which, per its docs,

> The zbar DLLs are included with the Windows Python wheels. On other operating systems, you will need to install the zbar shared library.

> Linux: sudo apt-get install libzbar0

> Mac OS X: brew install zbar

pyzbar works locally, but I can't install the shared library on Windows, so I'm getting

> ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

when I try to run the lambda. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: why not use WSL and create the lambda layer in there?

Comment: Your best bet would be to have a Linux development environment.  I haven't tried WSL as @emirc suggested but rather have used [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) with a Linux guest.  It's a pain as you need to figure out how to share the source code between the environments but it does work.  I'd be interested in knowing if WSL works instead as that might be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to download the library from pypi and then unzipped the file. Then, you must put the file in a folder called "python" and then, you have to zipp the folder nad upload to a layer. It must works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the zbar library on Amazon Linux as a system dependency before you do `pip install pyzbar`. The pyzbar package does not include a precompiled zbar library on Linux.

Amazon Linux 2 is based on Red Hat, so it uses `yum` as a package manager, not `apt-get`.

You'll need to install the zbar package in Amazon, I don't know the exact package name to use in Amazon Linux, but you're going to need to install it with something like `yum install zbar`.

Alternatively, if you can't make zbar works in Red Hat/Amazon Linux 2, you might want to use a container-based lambda, and use a Ubuntu or Debian base image, as they're the Linux distro that's officially supported by zbar.